# Error while creating context in Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I am developing a WPF application that uses Entity Framework v.6 with the approach Code First to build and manage a local database which is created on the client computer itself.

When I install the application on a client computer and launch it, I receive the following error when the context tries to create the database:

> Expansion of |DataDirectory| failed while processing the connection string. Ensure that |DataDirectory| is set to a valid fully-qualified path.

In `app.config` I have set the following configuration of Entity Framework:

```
<entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
         <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
   </defaultConnectionFactory>
   <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
   </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

My context class contains the following code:

```
class EntityContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Volunteer> Volunteers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Motivation> Motivations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PaymentType> PaymentTypes { get; set; }

    public EntityContext() : base("StaccoDataBase")
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EntityContext>());
    }
}
```

I have tried to fix the problem setting the `|DataDirectory|` in the `App.xaml.cs` as follows:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    currentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Directories.DBDirectory);
}
```

But the issue still persists.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: What does your `StaccoDataBase` connection string in your config file look like??

Comment: `StaccoDataBase` is just the name I choose for the Database. However, after your question, I tried also to configure the Database with a connectionstring rather than just the name, what I did was the following:

`public EntityContext() : base(connectionString)`

with

`string baseConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDBFilename={0}\\StaccoDataBase; integrated security=SSPI";
string connectionString = string.Format(baseConnectionString, Directories.DBDirectory);`

After running on client I received "SQL Network Interface, error: 52"

Comment: I have installed LocalDB on the client machine from the SQL Server 2017 Express, choosing Download Media and then LocalDB

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess - what if you used this connection string:

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|StaccoDataBase.mdf; integrated security=SSPI
```

First of all, use the `|DataDirectory|` directly in your connection string (don't "inject" it via that `string.Format()` call), and secondly, add the `.mdf` extension to the database file you want to attach.

Also, I'd store this connection string in the `app.config` - don't create it at runtime, because the constructor call here:

```
public EntityContext() : base("StaccoDataBase")
```

will try to find `StaccoDataBase` as a connection string name in your config file.

So use this:

**app.config**:

```
<configuration>
.....
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="StaccoDataBase"
             connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|StaccoDataBase.mdf; integrated security=SSPI"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <connectionStrings>   
    .....
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have tried following your suggestion, I have added the same connection string specified by you to the App.config and modified the context in order to use that connection string. When I launched the deployed app on the client computer I received the following error: SQL Network Interfaces, error 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified name for the database instance is not valid